# Заменить картинкам в src относительный путь на абсолютный

Tags: php, phpquery

Следующей строкой:     `$get_news_page_content->find('.content')->html();`  я беру `html` код нужного мне блока, но `src` у картинок данного блока имеют относительный путь.

Как мне пройтись по всем `img` в данном блоке и заменить относительный путь на путь вида: `example.com/images/test.jpg` и далее вывести на экран получившейся `html` код но уже с заменёнными путями у `img` ?

Comment: А что мешает построить DOM из взятого куска и пройтись там по всем изображениям с изменением `src`?

Comment: как потом вывести на экран получившейся html код но уже с заменёнными путями у img ?

Comment: Так же - `$obj->html()`. Или `(string) $obj`.

Comment: уже разобрался сам,  дико извиняюсь за ваше потраченное время.

Comment: На счёт "сам" - может быть, но не стоит удалять вопросы, они могут помочь другим пользователям.

Comment: @Other но только при наличии ответа!

Comment: спасибо. не знал, новенький здесь.

Comment: @alexolut Дал ответ, Вы довольны? :)

Comment: @Other нет. Я вечно недовольный >:-}

Comment: @alexolut Весело быть Вами :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$code = ''; // Your parsed html
$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($code);
$domain = 'http://yourhost.com';

foreach($doc->find('img') as $img) {
  $img = pq($img);
  $img->attr('src', $domain . $img->attr('src'));
}

$result = $doc->html();
```